# How do i configure a virtual host for Nuxt app in devlopment mode?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Vue CLI we can do something like this:

in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'example.test',
    https: false
  }
}
```

But how do i do this in Nuxt app?

I tried in `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
server: {
    host: 'example.test',
  },
```

But this did not work.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: This works fine for me locally. What is the issue you experience?

Comment: It does not open app in given host. It opens in my local ip LAN :)

Comment: And if you navigate to the host directly in your browser, with the appropriate schema and port?

Comment: Oh yeh. Manually putting port it works. But why it is not starting i mean showing that message in the terminal?

Comment: It's nothing you're doing wrong. I have the same issue, I've just ignored it for 2 years and manually navigate my way there. An annoyance for sure.

Comment: Yeh) Anyways. Thank you so much for your help :)  you may answer this question. I will accept that :)